# ERROR when returning hasura variables - Auth Webhook - AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, hasura

I am trying to return the hasura variables in a `nodejs 12` AWS Lambda but I get the error:

> GraphQL error: Invalid response from authorization hook: Error in $.hasuraVariables: parsing Text failed, expected String, but encountered Object

My code:

```
let hasuraVariables = {
    "X-Hasura-Role": "user", 
    "X-Hasura-User-Id": user.id, 
};

if (user.publisher && user.publisher.id) {
    Object.assign(hasuraVariables, {
        "X-Hasura-Publisher-Id": user.publisher.id.toString()
    }) 
}

const body = JSON.stringify({
    hasuraVariables
});
console.log("body", body)

return {
    "statusCode": "200",
    "body": body
}
```

If I log the `body` its:

> {"hasuraVariables":{"X-Hasura-Role":"user","X-Hasura-User-Id":"d61ea04f-421b-48a8-92a2-de6d00491425","X-Hasura-Publisher-Id":"110"}}

If I return the variables without stringify first:

```
return {
    "statusCode": "200",
    "body": hasuraVariables
}
```

I get the error:

> GraphQL error: Invalid response from authorization hook: Error in $: Failed reading: satisfy. Expecting object key at ''X-Hasura-Role':'user','X-Hasura-User-Id':'d61ea04f-421b-48a8-92a2-de6d00491425','X-Hasura-Pub'

What is the correct way to return the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use

```js
const body = JSON.stringify(hasuraVariables);
```

instead of

```js
const body = JSON.stringify({
    hasuraVariables
});
```

From the [docs](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/webhook.html) the response should be an object with the key/value header pairs directly, not below a `hasuraVariables` key like you're doing. [This example](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/30ef72bc9398076c0a0bc7a3ba3803ae3e822a8a/community/boilerplates/auth-webhooks/nodejs-express/server.js#L37) also illustrates how you should make this response.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I guess I added the curly braces without thinking.